# Constraint Layout not matching Scroll View height

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I've put inside a constraint layout a image and a heading layout which is not supposed to scroll and a scroll view which contains another constraint layout with some views. When I try to resize the constraint layout inside scroll view, The width changes accordingly, however the height not. I'd like the constraint layout height to match the height of its scrollview as I intend to add more text boxes and buttons for a registration form. Right now the two boxes are squeezed and the constraint layout height is not increasing.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/MistyRose"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:hint="Name"
                android:inputType="text"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="12dp" />

    <EditText
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp" 
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should put some constraints to your views in the container of the scroll view and make the scrollview stretch its content to fill the viewport with `android:fillViewport="true"`

Code here:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/MistyRose"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="203dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.016" />

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" android:fillViewport="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="46dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="46dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
                    android:hint="Email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```